# How to turn an IEnumerable (without type) into an IQueryable<T>?

Tags: c#, linq, collections, ienumerable, iqueryable

Having used LINQ quite a bit I am stumbling over a basic task today:

Having an `IQueryable<T>` out of an `IEnumerable` (without a type specified).

Specifically I want to query over parameters of an [SqlParameterCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). This is deriving from `IDataParameterCollection, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable` as [described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbparametercollection.aspx). However, these are all without the type specified.

Thus my question boils down to: **How to use LINQ to query over an SqlParameterCollection?**

Here's what I have done (the compiler did not complain):

```
IQueryable<SqlParameter> queryable = 
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AsQueryable().Cast<SqlParameter>();
    //throws ArgumentException "source is not IEnumerable<>"
```

*Note: I have searched quite a bit, but everyone is talking about `IEnumerable<T>` which is fairly easy to query using `AsQueryable()` of course.*

Comment: You can do `AsQueryable();` on `IEnumerable` to give you `IQueryable` (rather then `IQueryable<T>`, is that not enough?

Comment: Why do you need an `IQueryable<T>` from a parameter collection? It's all in memory, so `IEnumerable<T>` should be quite enough. Just in case you're not sure how to get `IEnumerable<T>` from plain `IEnumerable`, use `Cast<T>` method.

Comment: Expanding on what @dasblinkenlight said, what can you not do on `IEnumerable` that you can on `IQueryable`?

Comment: @DavidG Er, hm...querying the collection is only possible with IQueryable AFAIK.

Comment: @Marcel Not really. You can use all normal linq queries on `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @DavidG You are right of course. I really feel like a beginner today. Time to leave into the weekend :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am interested in the reason why you want to do this.
This should do what you explained:

```
public IQueryable<T> AsQueryable<T>(IEnumerable list)
{
    return list.Cast<T>().AsQueryable();   
}
```

Call like this:

```
IQueryable<SqlParameter> query = AsQueryable<SqlParameter>(sqlParameterCollection);
```

Comment: Ah, yes, this did it. I need to cast BEFORE calling AsQueryable(), not afterwards, as I have done initially. Stupid mistake by me.

Comment: To work with the values I think that all you really need is that `.Cast<T>()` part. I'm not sure what benefit adding `.AsQueryable()` adds here.